# Can i get value as number by using heightAnchor?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, snapkit

I am a new iOS programming and I am lack at technical part. I am stuck with one issue, I am creating an app which is programmatically and when I set `autoLayout` using [`SnapKit`](https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit) library, I am unable to get the height of my view.

Here is my code:

```
detailExploreEachCell.callButton.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in

        make.trailing.equalTo(detailExploreEachCell.divideView.snp.leading)
        make.height.equalTo(profileOverlayComponents.opacityDetailEachExplore).dividedBy(4.5)
        make.width.equalTo(profileOverlayComponents.opacityDetailEachExplore).dividedBy(2.5)
        make.top.equalTo(profileOverlayComponents.profileView.snp.bottom).offset(-20)

    }
```

Now I want to get value height as number, but I unable to get it

```
print("Height of call button \(detailExploreEachCell.callButton.frame.size.height)")
```

it returns me null.

Comment: Give us more context. Where are you printing it? Also, are the values you use to set the height valid?

Comment: The subview probably not yet laid out, try overriding `viewDidLayoutSubviews` in the custom `UITableViewCell` class, like so `override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews();
    print(self.callButton.frame.size.height)
}`

Comment: I print height below setting constraint. And value is correct and display is what i wanted. But i want to get its value as number because i want to adjust its top equal to half of full height value.

Comment: Off-topic, when you are new to `Swift`, you should follow the simple track by learning the basic stuff provided by Apple and obviously you can achieve anything with that before going for third party solutions. Working with third party libraries also require some learning and if you don't know how things work normally it will make your life difficult.

Comment: @Kamran yes sir! Thank for your advice. I will try to figure it out